# CakePHP 3 Http Client timeout error handling

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, httpresponse

I'm trying to use the [CakePHP 3 Http Client](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html) to check urls for their response status code (404, 301, 200 etc)

```
$http = new Client();
$response = $http->get($links[$i]['url'],[],['timeout' => '10']);
$links[$i]['http_status'] = $response->statusCode();
```

However, if I come across a url that timesout, the entire script fails.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to add error handling so that if it does timeout, I can log it and move on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try then to increase your timeout. It is 10s right now. Increase an check. It may be your internet connection or maybe URL is not responding well.

Comment: One of the urls that is forcing the error is actually a website that is no longer valid, so no amount of waiting will solve that problem, I need to be able to handle the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use try/catch.  I had tried this initially but missed the \ before Exception on the catch

```
try {
    // code
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: I tried try & catch but page still breaks. and error handling didn't work.